# Can I use strtok() in a Linux Kernel Module?

Tags: c, string, module, linux-kernel

I need to do a parse on the data written to my module, and the use of the strtok() function of string.h would be useful. However I've tried

```
#include <string.h>
```

and

```
#include <linux/string.h>
```

with no success. Is this possible? Or will I have to write my own strtok function?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no `strtok` in the valid Linux Kernel API. You will have to write your own. See the section [String Manipulation](http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~exr/teaching/lectures/systems/08_09/docs/kernelAPI/x1820.html) in the Linux Kernel API.

BTW, I would suggest staying away from `strtok` (or anything `strtok`-like). It's not reentrant and is unsafe in kernel code (which is inherently multithreaded).

If you're going to duplicate the function, consider duplicating `strtok_r`.

Comment: Ok awesome, at least I know for sure I have to write my own now, Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

The latest kernel library has this, which may do what you need:

```
/**
 * strsep - Split a string into tokens
 * @s: The string to be searched
 * @ct: The characters to search for
 *
 * strsep() updates @s to point after the token, ready for the next call.
 *
 * It returns empty tokens, too, behaving exactly like the libc function
 * of that name. In fact, it was stolen from glibc2 and de-fancy-fied.
 * Same semantics, slimmer shape. ;)
 */
```

Answer (score 2):

> char *strsep(char **s, const char *ct)

would be the function that you are looking for.
[You can look it up in lxr, source/lib/string.c, line 589 (for version/release 4.6)](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/lib/string.c#L589)