# error: implicit declaration of function 'strtok_r'

Tags: linux, netfilter

I am a newbie in Linux programming (Linux 3.7.10).  I tried to compile a program that I got for github but run in to problems with the error.  The main program is from ntop where I downloaded the ndpi (https://svn.ntop.org/svn/ntop/trunk/nDPI/) and that compiled ok.  The second part is the kernel mode filter that I got from github (https://github.com/ewildgoose/ndpi-netfilter).

First, I could not locate strtok_r function declared in any of the header files. I searched the whole system, is it a prebuild function with in the system?.   Please any pointers would be highly appreciated.  Thanks.

```
CC [M]  /home/mtot/ndpi/ndpi-netfilter/src/ndpi_cpy/lib/protocols/http.o
/home/mtot/ndpi/ndpi-netfilter/src/ndpi_cpy/lib/protocols/http.c: In function     'check_content_type_and_change_protocol':

/home/mtot/ndpi/ndpi-netfilter/src/ndpi_cpy/lib/protocols/http.c:610:4: error: implicit declaration of function 'strtok_r' [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]

/home/mtot/ndpi/ndpi-netfilter/src/ndpi_cpy/lib/protocols/http.c:610:10: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]

/home/mtot/ndpi/ndpi-netfilter/src/ndpi_cpy/lib/protocols/http.c:617:14: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]

/home/mtot/ndpi/ndpi-netfilter/src/ndpi_cpy/lib/protocols/http.c:623:9: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]

/home/mtot/ndpi/ndpi-netfilter/src/ndpi_cpy/lib/protocols/http.c:627:11: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]

/home/mtot/ndpi/ndpi-netfilter/src/ndpi_cpy/lib/protocols/http.c:632:13: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]

cc1: some warnings being treated as errors

make[2]: *** [/home/mtot/ndpi/ndpi-netfilter/src/ndpi_cpy/lib/protocols/http.o] Error 1

make[1]: *** [_module_/home/mtot/ndpi/ndpi-netfilter/src] Error 2
```

---

Adding more details

I have located the string.h that has the strtok_r in the /usr/include.  What I did was to add the  in the http.c file and also the -I/usr/include in the ccflags-y in the Makefile.  I got the following errors.  Help really needed.  Thanks.

```
CC [M]  /home/mtot/ndpi/ndpi-netfilter/src/ndpi_cpy/lib/protocols/http.o
  In file included from include/linux/compiler.h:48:0,
                 from include/uapi/linux/stddef.h:1,
  `enter code here`               from include/linux/stddef.h:4,
                 from /usr/src/linux-3.7.10/include/uapi/linux/posix_types.h:4,
                 from include/uapi/linux/types.h:13,
                 from include/linux/types.h:5,
                 from include/uapi/linux/byteorder/little_endian.h:11,
                 from include/linux/byteorder/little_endian.h:4,
                 from /usr/src/linux-3.7.10/arch/x86/include/asm/byteorder.h:4,
                 from /home/mtot/ndpi/ndpi-netfilter/src/ndpi_cpy/include/ndpi_main.h:49,
                 from /home/mtot/ndpi/ndpi-netfilter/src/ndpi_cpy/include/ndpi_protocols.h:29,
                 from /home/mtot/ndpi/ndpi-netfilter/src/ndpi_cpy/lib/protocols/http.c:25:
include/linux/compiler-gcc.h:93:0: warning: "__attribute_const__" redefined [enabled by default]
In file included from /usr/include/features.h:375:0,
                 from /usr/include/string.h:25,
                 from /home/mtot/ndpi/ndpi-netfilter/src/ndpi_cpy/lib/protocols/http.c:24:
/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:237:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
In file included from include/linux/compiler.h:48:0,
                 from include/uapi/linux/stddef.h:1,
                 from include/linux/stddef.h:4,
                 from /usr/src/linux-3.7.10/include/uapi/linux/posix_types.h:4,
                 from include/uapi/linux/types.h:13,
                 from include/linux/types.h:5,
                 from include/uapi/linux/byteorder/little_endian.h:11,
                 from include/linux/byteorder/little_endian.h:4,
                 from /usr/src/linux-3.7.10/arch/x86/include/asm/byteorder.h:4,
                 from /home/mtot/ndpi/ndpi-netfilter/src/ndpi_cpy/include/ndpi_main.h:49,
                 from /home/mtot/ndpi/ndpi-netfilter/src/ndpi_cpy/include/ndpi_protocols.h:29,
                 from /home/mtot/ndpi/ndpi-netfilter/src/ndpi_cpy/lib/protocols/http.c:25:
include/linux/compiler-gcc.h:112:0: warning: "__always_inline" redefined [enabled by default]
In file included from /usr/include/features.h:375:0,
                 from /usr/include/string.h:25,
                 from /home/mtot/ndpi/ndpi-netfilter/src/ndpi_cpy/lib/protocols/http.c:24:
/usr/include/sys/cdefs.h:308:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
In file included from include/linux/bitops.h:22:0,
                 from include/linux/kernel.h:10,
                 from include/linux/skbuff.h:17,
                 from include/linux/ip.h:20,
                 from /home/mtot/ndpi/ndpi-netfilter/src/ndpi_cpy/include/ndpi_main.h:105,
                 from /home/mtot/ndpi/ndpi-netfilter/src/ndpi_cpy/include/ndpi_protocols.h:29,
                 from /home/mtot/ndpi/ndpi-netfilter/src/ndpi_cpy/lib/protocols/http.c:25:
/usr/src/linux-3.7.10/arch/x86/include/asm/bitops.h:406:19: error: static declaration of 'ffs' follows non-static declaration
In file included from /usr/src/linux-3.7.10/arch/x86/include/asm/string.h:4:0,
                 from include/linux/string.h:17,
                 from include/linux/bitmap.h:8,
                 from include/linux/cpumask.h:11,
                 from /usr/src/linux-3.7.10/arch/x86/include/asm/cpumask.h:4,
                 from /usr/src/linux-3.7.10/arch/x86/include/asm/msr.h:18,
                 from /usr/src/linux-3.7.10/arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h:20,
                 from /usr/src/linux-3.7.10/arch/x86/include/asm/thread_info.h:22,
                 from include/linux/thread_info.h:54,
                 from include/linux/preempt.h:9,
                 from include/linux/spinlock.h:50,
                 from include/linux/mm_types.h:8,
                 from include/linux/kmemcheck.h:4,
                 from include/linux/skbuff.h:18,
                 from include/linux/ip.h:20,
                 from /home/mtot/ndpi/ndpi-netfilter/src/ndpi_cpy/include/ndpi_main.h:105,
                 from /home/mtot/ndpi/ndpi-netfilter/src/ndpi_cpy/include/ndpi_protocols.h:29,
                 from /home/mtot/ndpi/ndpi-netfilter/src/ndpi_cpy/lib/protocols/http.c:25:
/usr/src/linux-3.7.10/arch/x86/include/asm/string_64.h:64:5: error: expected identifier or '(' before '__extension__'
/usr/src/linux-3.7.10/arch/x86/include/asm/string_64.h:64:5: error: expected identifier or '(' before ')' token
In file included from include/linux/bitmap.h:8:0,
                 from include/linux/cpumask.h:11,
                 from /usr/src/linux-3.7.10/arch/x86/include/asm/cpumask.h:4,
                 from /usr/src/linux-3.7.10/arch/x86/include/asm/msr.h:18,
                 from /usr/src/linux-3.7.10/arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h:20,
                 from /usr/src/linux-3.7.10/arch/x86/include/asm/thread_info.h:22,
                 from include/linux/thread_info.h:54,
                 from include/linux/preempt.h:9,
                 from include/linux/spinlock.h:50,
                 from include/linux/mm_types.h:8,
                 from include/linux/kmemcheck.h:4,
                 from include/linux/skbuff.h:18,
                 from include/linux/ip.h:20,
                 from /home/mtot/ndpi/ndpi-netfilter/src/ndpi_cpy/include/ndpi_main.h:105,
                 from /home/mtot/ndpi/ndpi-netfilter/src/ndpi_cpy/include/ndpi_protocols.h:29,
                 from /home/mtot/ndpi/ndpi-netfilter/src/ndpi_cpy/lib/protocols/http.c:25:
include/linux/string.h:38:12: error: expected identifier or '(' before '__extension__'
include/linux/string.h:38:12: error: expected identifier or '(' before ')' token
include/linux/string.h:41:12: error: expected identifier or '(' before '__extension__'
include/linux/string.h:53:15: error: expected identifier or '(' before '__extension__'
include/linux/string.h:83:15: error: expected identifier or '(' before '__extension__'
include/linux/string.h:83:15: error: expected identifier or '(' before ')' token
include/linux/string.h:86:15: error: expected identifier or '(' before '__extension__'
include/linux/string.h:86:15: error: expected identifier or '(' before ')' token
include/linux/string.h:89:24: error: expected identifier or '(' before '__extension__'
include/linux/string.h:89:24: error: expected identifier or '(' before ')' token
include/linux/string.h:92:24: error: expected identifier or '(' before '__extension__'
include/linux/string.h:92:24: error: expected identifier or '(' before ')' token
make[2]: *** [/home/mtot/ndpi/ndpi-netfilter/src/ndpi_cpy/lib/protocols/http.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/mtot/ndpi/ndpi-netfilter/src] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-3.7.10'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

-----MakeFile

```
NDPI_PATH2 := ${NDPI_PATH}/src
NDPI_SRC := ndpi_cpy
NDPI_PRO := ${NDPI_SRC}/lib/protocols
NDPI_THIRD := $(NDPI_SRC)/lib/third_party/src
SYS_HDR := /usr/include

ccflags-y += -I${src}/${NDPI_SRC}/include -I${src}/${NDPI_SRC}/lib -I${src}/${NDPI_SRC}/lib/third_party/include -I${SYS_HDR} -DOPENDPI_NETFILTER_MODULE


EXTRA_CFLAGS := $(ccflags-y)

#MODULES_DIR := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)
#KERNEL_DIR := ${MODULES_DIR}/build

obj-m := xt_ndpi.o
xt_ndpi-y := main.o \
                ${NDPI_SRC}/lib/ndpi_main.o \
                ${NDPI_THIRD}/ahocorasick.o \
                ${NDPI_THIRD}/node.o \
                ${NDPI_THIRD}/sort.o \
                ${NDPI_PRO}/afp.o \
                ${NDPI_PRO}/http.o 


all:
        if test -d ${NDPI_SRC}; then \
                cp ${NDPI_PATH2}/* ${NDPI_SRC} -R; \
        else \
                mkdir ${NDPI_SRC}; \
                cp ${NDPI_PATH2}/* ${NDPI_SRC} -R; \
        fi
        make -C ${KERNEL_DIR} M=$$PWD;
        rm -r ${NDPI_SRC}
modules:
        make -C ${KERNEL_DIR} M=$$PWD $@;
modules_install:
        make -C ${KERNEL_DIR} M=$$PWD $@;
        depmod -a;
clean:
        make -C ${KERNEL_DIR} M=$$PWD $@;
```

Comment: What Linux distribution are you using? (3.7.10 is the kernel version; that's not useful.) `strtok_r` is not defined by standard C, though it is defined by POSIX. On my system, `man strtok_r` indicates that you need to define one of several feature test macros to use it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I use strtok() in a Linux Kernel Module?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246618/can-i-use-strtok-in-a-linux-kernel-module)

Answer (score 2):

`strtok_r` is typically in `string.h`. On a Linux system with man-pages installed you can do

```
man strtok_r
```

and that will give the manual page:

```
STRTOK(3)                  Linux Programmer’s Manual                 STRTOK(3)

NAME
   strtok, strtok_r - extract tokens from strings

SYNOPSIS
   #include <string.h>

   char *strtok(char *str, const char *delim);

   char *strtok_r(char *str, const char *delim, char **saveptr);
...
```

The `include` line tells you which file it is in (and must include in your code that uses it). Have you checked to see if you have `string.h` on your system? It is typically under `/usr/include`.

A lot of distributions have development packages, have you installed such packages to gain a fully development environment?

Comment: Ok. I found the string.h in /usr/include and it has the strtok_r defined but the Makefile is compiling it against the Kernel "linux/include".  The string.h there does not contain the definition for strtok_r.    Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: Oh, you're compiling kernel code. The kernel is a quite different programming environment than user space. Quite possibly `strtok_r` just isn't available.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I am trying to compile a kernel loadable module within the netfilter (iptables) framework. Anyway of getting the strtok_r in without breaking the kernel afterwards.   Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Type

```
man strtok_r
```

in a terminal. You should get a man page like [strtok_r(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok_r.3.html) (please follow that link).

Be sure to have installed the appropriate development and documentation packages like `libc6-dev` (or `libc-dev`), `glibc-doc`, `manpages-dev`. (The actual name depends upon the distribution).