# Implicit Declaration of Function ‘strtok_r’ Despite Including <string.h>

Tags: c, string, tokenize, strtok, gcc-warning

I have the following code to tokenize a string containing lines separated by `\n` and each line has integers separated by a `\t`:

```
void string_to_int_array(char file_contents[BUFFER_SIZE << 5], int array[200][51]) {
  char *saveptr1, *saveptr2;
  char *str1, *str2;
  char delimiter1[2] = "\n";
  char delimiter2[2] = " ";
  char line[200];
  char integer[200];
  int j;
  for(j = 1, str1 = file_contents; ; j++, str1 = NULL) {
    line = strtok_r(str1, delimiter1, &saveptr1);

    if (line == NULL) {
      break;
    }


    for (str2 = line; ; str2 = NULL) {
      integer = strtok_r(str2, delimiter2, &saveptr2);
      if (integer == NULL) {
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

(Have included only the relevant function here, the complete, if required, is [here](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/7553221/).)

However, when I try to compile this code using:

```
gcc -m64 -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-qual -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes file_read.c
```

I get the following warnings:

```
file_read.c:49:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘strtok_r’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     line = strtok_r(str1, delimiter1, &saveptr1);
     ^
file_read.c:49:10: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char[200]’ from type ‘int’
     line = strtok_r(str1, delimiter1, &saveptr1);
          ^
file_read.c:59:15: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char[200]’ from type ‘int’
       integer = strtok_r(str2, delimiter2, &saveptr2);
               ^
```

Line nos 49 and 59 correspond to the `strtok_r` call.

As you can see, I have included `string.h` in my file (which is where `strtok_r` is declared), still I get the implicit declaration warning for `strtok_r`.

Any insights as to how I can remove the warning is appreciated.

I am using gcc 4.8.2 on ubuntu 14.04 64-bit desktop.

Comment: Regarding your implicit declaration, `strtok_r` should be brought in correctly using `string.h`, but it is a POSIX-2001 feature, and you should ensure it is included. Either `#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200112L` before including any of the standard headers, or provide it via `-D` option on your command line switches for your compiler. This, of course, assuming your implementation supports it, and I certainly would expect yours would.

Comment: @WhozCraig: I don't see using `#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE ` in the manual page for `strtok_r`, how do I know I should be doing that?

Comment: See the *Feature Test Macro Requirements* in the [**man page**](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html). I assume you're using glibc on your platform. There are other ways it can be sucked in, some of which may be predefine by default when you set your standard switch (-std=c99 likely won't turn it on, for example, while -std=c11 probably would. haven't tested that but I wouldn't be surprised).

Comment: @WhozCraig: Thanks! Your comment along with nos' answer helped resolve this. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: possible duplicated question. check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246618/can-i-use-strtok-in-a-linux-kernel-module and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19388774/error-implicit-declaration-of-function-strtok-r

Comment: @JohnSmith: Doesn't seem to look like that, its specifically for kernel modules.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`strtok_r` is not a standard C function. You have asked for only C99 by using the `-std=c99`compiler flag, so the header files (of glibc) will only make the standard C99 functions in `string.h` available to you.

Enable extensions by using `-std=gnu99` , or by defining one of the extensions, shown in the manpage of strtok , that supports strtok_r before including `string.h`. E.g.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <string.h>
```

Note that the code have other problems too,  `strtok_r` returns a `char *` , but you are trying to assign that to a char array in `integer = strtok_r(str2, delimiter2, &saveptr2);`. Your `integer` variable should be a `char *`

Comment: Thanks! Does that mean `strtok_r` reduces the portability and is available only on linux?

Comment: Yes, it might reduce portability. However strtok_r is defined by posix, so at least pretty much all unix like system will have it.

Comment: @i08in `strtok_r` definitely reduces portability, as it is a *nix only function, the windows equivalent being `strtok_s`.

Answer (score 3):

Same problem with GCC 7.4.2 on Debian

Solved using `__strtok_r` or `-std=gnu99` or adding a protoype after includes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024

extern char *strtok_r(char *, const char *, char **);
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using 4.8.2 and ubuntu 14.04 64bit too. But I got different errors.

```
    incompatible types when assigning to type 'char[200]' from type 'char *' 
        line = strtok_r(str1, delimiter1, &saveptr1);
             ^
```

here, `line` is declared 'char[200]' but `strtok_r` returns `char*`.

Similar errors at line for `integer = ...`.

To get rid of these compile errors, you can declare something like `char *line;`.

For the warning about implicit declaration, check this

[Can I use strtok() in a Linux Kernel Module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246618/can-i-use-strtok-in-a-linux-kernel-module)

Comment: `line` and `integer` were `char *`s previously. I had changed that assuming the seg faults were because of assignment to a char pointer, but changing that didn't help: you can try changing `line` to a `char*` instead of `char line[200]`. Don't you get warnings for implicit declaration of `strtok_r` when you compile them using the gcc options I have mentioned in the question?

Comment: I hope you have used the gcc options I have mentioned in the question, haven't you?

Comment: Any reasons you skipped that? I included that as part of what I had read as recommended options I should use while compiling C programs here on SO.

Comment: Thanks, you gave a great insight as to the cause, but nos answered helped it solve.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that the function `strtok_r` returns a pointer to char, witch you are trying to assign to an array of char, so in order to make it work you have to declare your `line` and `integer` variables as a pointer of char, then allocate the memory with malloc.

```
void string_to_int_array(char file_contents[BUFFER_SIZE << 5], int array[200][51]) {
  char *saveptr1, *saveptr2;

  char *str1, *str2;

  char delimiter1[2] = "\n";
  char delimiter2[] = " ";
  char *line;
  char *integer;
  int j;
  line = (char*)malloc(200);
  integer = (char*)malloc(200);
  for(j = 1, str1 = file_contents; ; j++, str1 = NULL) {
    line = strtok_r(str1, delimiter1, &saveptr1);
    printf("%s\n", line);
    if (line == NULL) {
      break;
    }
    printf("end of first\n");

    for (str2 = line; ; str2 = NULL) {
    printf("begin of second\n");
      printf("asdf%s\n", line);
      integer = strtok_r(str2, delimiter2, &saveptr2);
      if (integer == NULL) {
        break;
      }
      printf("%s\n", integer);
    }
  }
}
```