# How can i pull two numbers from a string and convert them to two integer value in Linux Kernel?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, procfs

I have a string variable (It is a input from the user space ) and i need to pull two number inside of it . For example :

"123 + 12"  i need to create 2 substring from it . "123" and "12" .

Format of this string always will be like in the examples : "12 + 1" , "1 * 1" , "432 - 232" etc so  length of the string isn't a constant value . It is the biggest problem for me .

**How can i take these two numbers from the string and convert them to two integer value ?**  Can you show me a simple example ? How can i split the string by space character in Linux Kernel ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use strtok() in a Linux Kernel Module?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246618/can-i-use-strtok-in-a-linux-kernel-module)

Comment: strtok() and strsep() looks different . char *strtok(char *str, const char *delim)  , char *strsep(char **s, const char *ct)   @Tim

Comment: I was doing something just like this the other day.  I used `strspn` and `strcspn` to skip whitespace and isolate the numbers.  I used`kstrtoint` to convert the numbers to integers.  You'll have the additional task of checking for that `+` sign.

Comment: @anor, you have to be careful when parsing something like `3 - 2` vs. `3 + -2` vs. `3 -2` in case you are using signed values. Otherwise the idea is pretty simple, either you are using `sscanf()` or `isdigit()` + `kstrto*()` in a loop.